# Unable to update dataset: can't send resources as list of dictionaries

Tags: php, ckan

We've built a set of scripts in PHP using the CKAN API (running ckan version 2.5.7), but we haven't managed to successfully make a package_update call. If we don't send the resources with the POST data then they all get deleted, which we don't want. But I haven't found a way of sending them that CKAN will accept.

We're using cURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$dictionary);
```

where

```
$dictionary['resources'] = json_encode(
    array_map(
        function($resource) {
            return filter_out_unwanted_fields($resource); // returns an associative array
        },
        $all_resources_for_the_dataset
    )
);
```

When we run the API call, we get the error: `Only lists of dicts can be placed against subschema ('resources',), not <type 'unicode'>`

I interpret this as a complaint that the POSTed parameter is the unicode string returned by json_encode(). So what can I send through HTTP POST to make the API happy without deleting all my resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing an array into `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$dictionary);` you're sending the data as `multipart/form-data` ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)).

So CKAN is unwrapping the data as such, and ending up with a string for `resource` – the contents of that string being your serialised data: (`"[{}, {}, {}]"`)

I'm quite confident CKAN will accept the entire form data as a JSON object, so if you move the `json_encode` to encode the entire `$dictionary` (and maybe add a `Content-Type` header?) then CKAN should unravel that entirely, and thus give you a List of Dict objects for `resource` (`[{}, {}, {}]`)

Comment: Yes. That's it. I don't even seem to need to send a Content-Type header. "multipart/form-data" is required when uploading a file (for a resource) but since resources don't have subschema that's not going to be a problem. Thanks, you're a hero.